# GitFlow - is it OK for `develop` to become unstable, or must it always be kept stable?

Tags: git, git-flow

We use GitFlow in our small team. I am aware of the arguments against it, but we use it for the moment and it suits the team. Our code is all open source, on GitHub, and the `develop` branch is the default branch, and it is protected. My question is related to conflicting views about whether `develop` needs to be stable and whether it is OK for people to merge their feature branches into `develop` even if they fail CI tests on the branch (we use Jenkins and have enabled status checks on incoming branches into `develop`).

My manager (who is not a developer) is of the opinion that `develop` doesn't need to be stable, and he seems OK to merge his buggy branches into `develop`. I think this is lax and terrible - `develop` should be kept stable, and the onus is on the people merging into `develop` to run tests at their end and to merge in only when those branches are stable. An unstable `develop` branch means you propagate errors to everyone who is branching off `develop`, and there is no reason why other people should be responsible for fixing your test failures.

I think I'm right and my manager is wrong, but is there any guidance on offer about what is the correct approach to take in this situation?

Comment: If your manager doesn't understand the benefits of tests and CI you have a big problem. Saying that, it's not a valid SO question.

Comment: Only stable changes should be pushed to shared branches. Period. Unstable commits are what feature branches are for.

Comment: OK, I guess the question is a bit too general maybe, but if there was a more suitable forum for it, I would post it there. I am pretty sure 99% of good developers would have the sense that your default branch should be stable, but unfortunately when the manager is a non-technical person, and even worse, he is making contributions to the codebase, this is what we have to deal with.